# How to automatically run cmd.exe in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I made a project in eclipse. It would receive a string either Left, Right or Center through local socket. It successfully receives one of these strings but I don't know how to instruct the program what to do next.

I intend to compare the content of the received string and automatically run cmd.exe

```
while (true) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF()); //receives the string


            /*if (dataInputStream.readUTF()=="Center")
             * {
             *   //open cmd.exe
             * }
             */

            dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello!");
```

A copy of my project can be found at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xswz5qzcewee4ko/AACo8VZ_Iu0kFhn63kepOXlta?dl=0

I would really appreciate for any suggestion that you may want to give.

Comment: Please provide more details about your project. People would not download your code to understand what you are trying to do. What do you mean by opening cmd.exe ? Do you mean open the window cmd.exe on the computer ? There are lots of things to consider here. You can not just expect the command line window to appear on the screen. What if you do not have Windows running with graphical environment ?

Comment: Thank you for this also. Will do, through the standards and this in mind, next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Runtime API you can invoke cmd.exe. Please consider option which suits you best.

This will run commands from java

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir");
```

This will open cmd window from java code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","start"});
```

Comment: java.lang.ProcessBuilder is another option.

Comment: This was the one i was lacking! Thank you very much.